# Remove by id in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm struggling with removing record from my database via api.

First I get whole record from the API, and then when record is not filled the way I want I have an option of removing it by front end. I pass the object ID and want to remove it using mongoose method. However, no matter how I pass the id i cant seem to delete the record.

Here is the code of the remove route:

```
router.delete('/database/delete/', (req, res, next) => {
    let id = 'ObjectId("'.concat(req.body.id).concat('")');
    let id2 = req.body.id;
    console.log(id, id2)
    db.findByIdAndRemove(id).then((err, client) => {
        console.log(client)
        if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
        const response = {
            msg: "Client removed",
            success: true
        }
        return res.status(200).send(response);
    })
})
```

As you can see im trying to pass the id both ways, so the console log outputs both: `ObjectId("5a8ea050fe07b60eda004c6e")`  and `5a8ea050fe07b60eda004c6e`, both wont work. How can i solve this?

Comment: type of `ObjectId` is an `object` not a `string`. you may change to `new ObjectID(req.body.id);`

Comment: I dont think its a proper solution, since im using mongoose method to delete the record, not mongoDB. Im getting ObjectId is not defined eitherway. Besides, the proper id is "id2" without the objectId part

Comment: If `db` represents a Mongoose model then `db.findByIdAndRemove(req.body.id)` will work just fine since the id will be cast to `ObjectId` internally by Mongoose.

Comment: In mongoose `findByIdAndRemove` return `Query` and it is `Promise`, it means you should use `catch` to handle the error. And i don't know what is `db` define here.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose")
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

var id = ObjectId("5a8ea050fe07b60eda004c6e")
//for your case
let id2 = ObjectId(String(req.body.id))
console.log(typeof id) //it will show object
```

What you are doing is trying to make your `id` look like `ObjectId`. If you will check `typeof id` it will be **string** instead of **object**,